# Elastic Load Balancing with Tornado

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tornado, amazon-elb

I haven't been able to find any solid information online.

I'm curious to know if its possible (and how) to use the Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) service with Tornado.

If it isn't, whats the best alternative to using AWS as a scalable option with Tornado?

Comment: If you consider the point of tornado being a webserver and want to place an ELB in front of the Tornado; I would say why not. Go ahead and try it out. End of the day to start with you need port mappings and protocols to make the things running.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There's nothing special about Tornado here; it's just like using ELB with anything else. Do you have any more specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

For example our setup is `ELB->nginx->tornado`.

`nginx` is used for app specific proxy, cache and header magic, but can be thrown out of this chain or replaced with something else.

Comment: Thats great to hear. Could you provide me any resources on the matter?

Comment: This is what i'm using at the moment:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/awsgsg-wah-linux.pdf

Comment: @mojo do you need nginx at all? Can't you go ELB->tornado?

Comment: @Marius, we do need nginx, as I have mentioned we use it as a proxy. Nothing stops you from using ELB->tornado.